# Android Spinner specific list

Tags: android

So I've been trying my best and getting this Spinner to be able to change the list depending on the choices done. For example changing the say a Spinner devoted to floors, would yield a different set of spots when pressing the spot spinner:

XML format:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="202dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_weight="0.49" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="New Reservation"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="First Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Fname"
            android:layout_width="129dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Last Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Lname"
            android:layout_width="126dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="License"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/License"
            android:layout_width="126dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/Garage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/Garages"
            android:prompt="@string/GaragePrompt" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/Floor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/Floors"
            android:prompt="@string/FloorPrompt" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/Spot"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/Spots"
            android:prompt="@string/SpotPrompt" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Date"
            android:layout_width="122dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="date" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Time"
            android:layout_width="122dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="time" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/Reserve"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
             android:text="Reserve" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is one way of populating different values on a `Spinner` depending on the selection of another `Spinner`.

In the following case the `Spots` will change values with the selection of the `Floor` spinner. This is one way of doing it but might not be the best way...

Declare as class variables...

```
private Spinner floor, spot;
private ArrayAdapter<String> floorAdapter, spotAdapter;
```

In `onCreate`

```
floor = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Floor);
spot = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spot);

// NOTE: 
// You can populate the lists below from a resource array as well using ArrayAdapter.createFromResource.

List<String> floor = new ArrayList<String>();
floor.add("spot 1");
floor.add("spot 2");

List<String> spot1 = new ArrayList<String>();
spot1.add("spot1 item 1");
spot1.add("spot1 item 2");
spot1.add("spot1 item 3");

List<String> spot2 = new ArrayList<String>();
spot2.add("spot2 item 1");
spot2.add("spot2 item 2");
spot2.add("spot2 item 3");

floorAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, floor);
floor.setAdapter(floorAdapter);
floor.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Then do the following on the `onItemSelected` for the `floor` spinner...

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch(position) {
    case 0:
        spotAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spot1);
        spot.setAdapter(spotAdapter);
        break;
    case 1:
        spotAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spot2);
        spot.setAdapter(spotAdapter);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

As I mentioned above, you can load the list from an array as well using `ArrayAdapter.createFromResource`.

All the best.

Comment: I'm a tad confused with the secondary section. How can you add multiple changes to a spinner's list?

Comment: @macroquezada: What do you mean by secondary section? Do you mean the `switch case`?

Comment: I mean the switch case yes. Basically I want to swap out one array list with another one.

Comment: Yup. That is exactly what the switch case does. The `switch` is checking the `position` of the data selected in the `spinner`. The position starts from `0`. So if the user has selected `spot 1` in the `floor` spinner then the `spot` spinner will load `spot1` array list. And so on...

Comment: Gnarly, I'll give it a shot.